# Can I monitor for corrupt secondary index in Cassandra?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1, datastax-startup

Yesterday, I found a corrupted secondary index in our cluster. (DSE 4.8.10, c* 2.1.15). I verified the data was in the table using a SELECT statement. After using `nodetool rebuild_index cf tn idx_name`, I was able to get the correct query result using `select * from <table_name> where <pk> = 'x' and <idx_key> = 'y';`

My question is - Is there any way to detect, monitor or otherwise proactively look for possible secondary index corruption? I would really hate to have a broken, and undetected, secondary index in production.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now there isn't a "auto detect" feature for secondary indexes.  To be honest I would tend to recommend against them as they can have some long term issues.  There are some options like using the DSE Search feature that can give you much of the same function.